.desktop to a changing AppImage
I downloaded Cursor, the AI editor, as an AppImage, then created a .desktop file to easily launch it.
However, the shortcut soon becomes unusable as the AppImage is updated to a new version and the file name changes (e.g. the build numbers change in "cursor-0.42.5-build-24111460bf2loz1-x86_64.AppImage") .
I am not sure how this happens (perhaps auto-updates?), but I want to know if there's a way to use a regex in the .desktop file to catch any build number.

https://github.com/getcursor/cursor/issues/844#issuecomment-2080288303  maybe this will help to update the command in your desktop file. If it is possible with regex I don't know to be honest.

You can use AppImageLauncher to auto generate a .desktop file for your AppImage. It creates a new .desktop entry for each new AppImage that it sees, so it should be perfect for your usecase!
Please give me an upvote if this was helpful! Thanks!

Users of AppImageLauncher should avoid integrating unverified or suspicious AppImages, as these could exploit AppImageLauncher’s deep integration capabilities. This would be a potential security risk of using this app.
